# How to delete if the data for the days following each other are the same - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this;

| OwnerName | Date | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 2020-01-01 | 5.5 | 500 | 22.76 |
| Jack | 2020-01-02 | 4.7 | 650 | 33.75 |
| Jack | 2020-01-03 | 4.7 | 650 | 33.75 |
| Jack | 2020-01-04 | 4.7 | 650 | 33.75 |
| Jack | 2020-01-05 | 5.1 | 780 | 35.50 |
| Jack | 2020-01-06 | 6.8 | 340 | 20.75 |
| Jack | 2020-01-07 | 9.2 | 450 | 15.50 |
| Jack | 2020-01-08 | 9.2 | 450 | 15.50 |
| Jack | 2020-01-09 | 9.2 | 450 | 15.50 |
| Jack | 2020-01-10 | 9.2 | 450 | 15.50 |

If Value 1, Value 2, and Value 3 are the same for consecutive dates, how can I delete dates other than the earliest date from those dates?

According to this sample table, after the delete query, the table should be as follows;

| OwnerName | Date | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 2020-01-01 | 5.5 | 500 | 22.76 |
| Jack | 2020-01-02 | 4.7 | 650 | 33.75 |
| Jack | 2020-01-05 | 5.1 | 780 | 35.50 |
| Jack | 2020-01-06 | 6.8 | 340 | 20.75 |
| Jack | 2020-01-07 | 9.2 | 450 | 15.50 |

Table Script :

```
CREATE TABLE OwnerRateInfo(
   OwnerName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Date      DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Value1    DECIMAL(20,1) NOT NULL
  ,Value2    DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL
  ,Value3    DECIMAL(20,2) NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY(OwnerName,Date)
);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-01',5.5,500,22.76);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-02',4.7,650,33.75);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-03',4.7,650,33.75);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-04',4.7,650,33.75);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-05',5.1,780,35.50);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-06',6.8,340,20.75);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-07',9.2,450,15.50);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-08',9.2,450,15.50);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-09',9.2,450,15.50);
INSERT INTO OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) VALUES (N'Jack','2020-01-10',9.2,450,15.50);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which database are you use?

Comment: Your example is wrong based on the statement you provided. For the statement to be valid, record 3:value3 should be 33.75

Comment: Can you be more precise about what "yesterday" means to you? If you had a row `4, 2020-01-04, 5.5, 500, 22.76` should it stay or go?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Once you add DDL we'll know if `[Date]` is a `Date` and other helpful details. We seem to be assuming that "first date" means the earliest date rather than the one with the lowest `ID`.

Comment: Sorry for not giving details, I'm using T-SQL @Nour-AllahHussein

Comment: Thanks for your warning, I corrected the relevant value @RossBush

Comment: Thank you for the document, I am a beginner in these matters. I'm just trying to improve myself. Also I tried to make my question a little more descriptive by editing  @HABO

Comment: I apologize for the missing information I edited my question @CaiusJard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a start:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @OwnerRateInfo as Table(
   OwnerName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Date      DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Value1    DECIMAL(20,1) NOT NULL
  ,Value2    DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL
  ,Value3    DECIMAL(20,2) NOT NULL );

insert into @OwnerRateInfo(OwnerName,Date,Value1,Value2,Value3) values
  (N'Jack','2020-01-01',5.5,500,22.76),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-02',4.7,650,33.75),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-03',4.7,650,33.75),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-04',4.7,650,33.75),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-05',5.1,780,35.50),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-06',6.8,340,20.75),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-07',9.2,450,15.50),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-08',9.2,450,15.50),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-09',9.2,450,15.50),
  (N'Jack','2020-01-10',9.2,450,15.50);

select * from @OwnerRateInfo;

-- Number rows having the same   OwnerName ,   Value1 ,   Value2   and   Value3   by ascending   Date .
select OwnerName, [Date], Value1, Value2, Value3,
  Row_Number() over ( partition by OwnerName, Value1, Value2, Value3 order by [Date] ) as RN
  from @OwnerRateInfo;

-- Delete the undesirable rows.
-- The syntax to delete from a join is a bit peculiar, but such is life.
delete from @OwnerRateInfo
  from @OwnerRateInfo as ORI inner join (
    -- Get the numbered rows as shown in the previous example.
    select OwnerName, [Date], Value1, Value2, Value3,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by OwnerName, Value1, Value2, Value3 order by [Date] ) as RN
      from @OwnerRateInfo
      ) as ORIT
  on ORI.OwnerName = ORIT.OwnerName and ORI.[Date] = ORIT.[Date] and
    ORI.Value1 = ORIT.Value1 and ORI.Value2 = ORIT.Value2 and ORI.Value3 = ORIT.Value3 and
    ORIT.RN > 1; -- Keep the first match for each partition and delete the rest.

-- Display the result.
select * from @OwnerRateInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using a longwinded CASE LAG() statement to align records for deletion. The lag marks preceding records with duplicate values = 1. Joining that dataset with a delete statement will produce the desired result.

```
DELETE D FROM
    OwnerRateInfo D
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT OwnerName, Date,
            IsOneDayApartAndSameValues = CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerName,Value1,Value2,Value3 ORDER BY Date),Date)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM OwnerRateInfo  
    )AS K ON K.OwnerName = D.OwnerName AND K.Date=D.Date AND K.IsOneDayApartAndSameValues = 1

SELECT * FROM OwnerRateInfo
```

Output

```
OwnerName   Date    Value1  Value2  Value3
Jack    2020-01-01  5.5 500 22.76
Jack    2020-01-02  4.7 650 33.75
Jack    2020-01-05  5.1 780 35.50
Jack    2020-01-06  6.8 340 20.75
Jack    2020-01-07  9.2 450 15.50
```